# Program to scan my website and find all the pages which link to an external website

Tags: html, web-crawler

I would like to generate a list of all the web pages in my website (contains 500 pages and more) which link to an external website.

Before I start trying to code this one, I would like to know if something ready made exists so I don't go into all the hassle for nothing.

If you know of any, or have used any, please share.

Thanks

Comment: It should be asked at: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eventually, the easiest way was with an SQL Query in the database, so make sure you check if it is do able when you have a similar problem, via SQL before trying to find external programs.

Thanks to everyone for suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

For link checking, I use [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html).

Comment: If I am not mistaken this does not recurse into each and every page from the link given, therefore I would not know each external link without having to manually input each and every link of the webpage I want to check.

Comment: It recurses all links it finds on a given start page and all pages on the same domain, including outgoing external links. Just give it a try; it is blazing fast and free-of-charge.

Answer (score 2):

The [W3C link checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink) will give you a list of all the links and tell you which ones are working. It should be pretty trivial to scrap the output to show only external links.

Comment: I have noticed a small problem with this, it does not tell you where that link is situated. Having the link only is not enough, as I wouldn't know where I would have to change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a website sniffer ? There's a lot of free tools that can explore your website and list your pages.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Do you know a particular one which gives me all the external links?

Comment: I think that you will really enjoy that : https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Once you added your website, go into the Dashboard, then "Your site on the web". It tells you both internal and external links.

Answer (score 0):

SEOMOZ Pro Account - Sign up for free 30 day trial, best site crawler our there
http://www.seomoz.org/freetrial